The plugin requires a higher Android SDK version
I have an error after I added Firebase Auth plugin:

The plugin firebase_auth requires a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to the file C:\Users\HP\Desktop\app\test_i\android\app\build.gradle:     │
android {
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 23
}
}
Following this change, your app will not be available to users running Android SDKs below 23.                   │
Consider searching for a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the Android SDK instead.

But when I went to build.gradle I found it like this:
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.test_i"
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

I;ve tried to replace flutter.minSdkVersion with 23, like this:
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.test_i"
        minSdk =  23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

But it didn't work either, and gave me another error:

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... 7.8s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk... 1,870ms
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install C:\Users\HP\Desktop\app\test_ii\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure
[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone x86.

Any help, guys?


Try upgrading the firebase auth version in pubspec.yaml to the latest (or any)

firebase_auth: ^5.1.4 or firebase_auth: any

run flutter clean and then flutter pub get commands

Update:
Please update the minSdkVersion to 24 in build.gradle file

Didn't work out. It gives me the same error as the 1st one I mentioned.

Please try the above steps with the following setting

Update the build.gradle with the following

defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.test_i"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

with the setting i've mentioned about the pubspec.yaml
2. Then run  flutter clean and flutter pub get  commands

Same error. Nothing change.

Any other tips, Guys?

been searching almost 3 hours about this problem.
your solution saved me.
thanks mate

Finally, I found the solution:

1st error: Change "minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion" to "minSdk = 23". For me, it was 23, and it's the same SDK version given in the error.
2nd error: Increase the internal storage of my emulator through AVD, from 6 to 10 GB.

